# Force periods in "Ph.D. thesis" in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber

Using `biblatex` and Biber, I want my bibliography to say "Ph.D. thesis" (with periods) rather than "PhD thesis" (without). MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}
\begin{document}
Hello \cite{testphd}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and `refs.bib`:

```
@thesis{testphd,
  title       = {Thesis Title},
  author      = {Surname, Firstname},
  date        = {2010},
  institution = {Faculty of X, University of Y},
  type        = {phdthesis},
  location    = {Somewhere},
}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

What's the easiest way to do this? I don't want to change the `.bib` file ideally.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can redefine the bibstrings used by `biblatex` with `\DefineBibliographyStrings`

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{phdthesis = {Ph\adddot D\adddotspace thesis}}
```

`\adddot` inserts an abbreviation dot, `\adddotspace` inserts an abbreviation dot followed by a space (penalised by `abbrvpenalty`).