# Where is file for IEEE information stored in Windows Miktex installation to modify the @phdthesis entry?

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style

I am trying to modify the entry for `@phdthesis`  to show "PhD dissertation" instead of the normal "PhD thesis" as per the suggestion made [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175106/make-phd-citations-say-dissertation-rather-than-thesis).  However, on windows that has a Miktex installation, I cannot find the file where to make this change.  I am using this setup:

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}

%======================================================================================
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%======================================================================================
\usepackage[backref=false,
            defernumbers=true,
            style = ieee,
            %sorting=none,
            sortcites=true,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\addbibresource{yourbibliography.bib}% BibTeX
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{yourbibliography.bib}

@phdthesis{Cedra-Villafana:2005,
abstract = {Gust avo C erda-V illafan a, B .En g ., M.Eng. t1{\~{}} University of m{\~{}} BRISTOL},
author = {Cedra-Villafana, Gustavo},
school = {University of Bristol},
title = {{Artificial intelligence techniques in flood forecasting}},
url = {https://research-information.bristol.ac.uk/files/34499658/412360.pdf},
note = {(Date last accessed 06-May-2019)},
year = {2005}
}

\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

This is just some text \cite{Cedra-Villafana:2005}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty]


\end{document}
```

The closest that I came across was the ieeetr.bst file found in ...\user\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bst\bibtex.  I made the change here but it did not make a difference.

Is there a different place or .bst file that I have to modify to show up PhD dissertation in the references?

Thanks.

Comment: With biblatex you don't use this bst, changes are made differently. Also you should never change an original file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks for your input.  How do I go about to accomplish the task of having PhD dissertation show up instead of PhD thesis using biblatex then?

Comment: Add to your question a small complete example then someone will come and add the needed code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. MWE added. Thanks!

Comment: Very related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/393773/35864

Comment: @moewe, that answered my question.  Thanks!

Comment: I guess we can close this as a duplicate then, would you agree?

Comment: agreed. Is it preferable to delete this post then?

Comment: No, questions closed as duplicates remain searchable and can be useful signposts to point people in the right direction, especially if the duplicate uses new and different search terms and tags.